# SQL Pivot with multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Hello I have a table like so:

```
Building    Categories      Properties
-----------------------------------------
Building250 Structure       Steel
Building250 Security        Access Card
Building250 Security        Security Guard
Building250 Security        Fire Alarm System 
Building250 Security        Sprinklered
Building250 Security        Smoke or heat detectors
Building46  Structure       Brick
Building46  Structure       Steel
Building46  Walls           Steel Stud
Building46  Walls           Masonry
Building46  Washroom        OwnSpace
Building46  Washroom        Common
Building46  Security        Access Card
Building46  Security        Burglar Alarm
```

and I need to pivot it like so:

```
Building    Structure   Security           Walls       Washroom
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building250 Steel       Access Card     
                        Security Guard      
                        Fire Alarm System       
                        Sprinklered     
                        heat detectors      
Building46  Brick       Access Card       Steel Stud    OwnSpace
            Steel       Burglar Alarm     Masonry       Common 
                        Sprinklered
```

I tried SQL Pivot, but since it requires an aggregation, it returns only 1 property for a given category. Is there another way?

Here's my Pivot SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Category) 
                  FROM Buildings
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT Building, ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                SELECT Building, Category, Property, from Buildings
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                min(Property)
                for Category in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Comment: How did you try show the query.

Comment: Show what you tried. You'll get more input if you show your effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted Pivot can do aggregation and while there are workarounds possible you can accomplish what you need without pivot with something like the following.  You could also make it dynamic using the same method you would make a dynamic pivot.

```
Select B.Building, Str.Properties Structure, 
       Sec.Properties Security, Walls.Properties Walls, Wash.Properties Washroom
    From (Select Distinct Building From Table) B
    Left Join Table Str On Str.Building = B.Building And Categories = 'Structure'
    Left Join Table Sec On Sec.Building = B.Building And Categories = 'Security'
    Left Join Table Walls On Walls.Building = B.Building And Categories = 'Walls'
    Left Join Table Wash On Wash.Building = B.Building And Categories = 'Washroom'
```