# How to join multiple rows with the same value for a column

Tags: database, oracle

This may be hard to understand exactly what I'm asking so I apologize ahead of time.

I'm trying to join two tables in a database that have different primary Keys, the employee table has a primary key that is EmployeeID, and the contact table has a primary key that is ContactID. I tried joining them on the EmployeeID but I got too many duplicates of the same employee, just a different email address that is associated with the employee. I wish to ignore the contactID and query the tables to create an output that shows the name, ID, and lists the email addresses as well.

Is this possible?

Here's an example:

Employee Table:

```
EmployeeID | Employee Name | Address |
____________ ______________ __________

0001            John         123 Ave.
```

Contact Table:

```
ContactID |     Email     | EmployeeID|
__________ ______________ ______________ 
0001        abc@email.com   001
0002        bcd@email.com   001
```

My desired output would be:

```
EmployeeID| Name         |  Email1      |  Email2      |
__________ ______________ ______________ _______________

001       |  John        |abc@email.com| bcd@email.com
```

Comment: please add rdbms

Comment: maybe this question helps you, its a possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41768834/sql-pivot-with-multiple-values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server, you can use some dynamic SQL to accomplish what you want.

**tl;dr**: The code block at the end contains the SQL that you want.

---

First, we will hard code our query to give us what we want. Next, we'll look at using Dynamic SQL to make our lives easier. I'll be using the following example tables:

```
#Employee
+ ------ + ------------- + ----------- +
| EMP_Id | EMP_Name      | EMP_Address |
+ ------ + ------------- + ----------- +
| 1      | John Jacob    | 123 Ave.    |
| 2      | Ermit Schmidt | 101 St.     |
+ ------ + ------------- + ----------- +

#Contact
+ ------ + --------------- + ------ +
| CNT_Id | CNT_Email       | EMP_Id |
+ ------ + --------------- + ------ +
| 1      | abc@email.com   | 1      |
| 2      | bcd@email.com   | 1      |
| 3      | es@email.com    | 2      |
| 4      | es12@email.com  | 2      |
| 5      | es_01@email.com | 2      |
+ ------ + --------------- + ------ +
```

**1) Hard Code**

To start, we have to rank the `#Contact` table in order for us to select each email address from each employee. The following query does just that

```
select  *
    from #Employee emp
    left join (
        select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by emp_id order by cnt_id) as Ranking
            from #Contact
    ) cnt on cnt.EMP_Id = emp.EMP_Id
```

and produces a table like

```
+ ------ + ------------- + ----------- + ------ + --------------- + ------ + ------- +
| EMP_Id | EMP_Name      | EMP_Address | CNT_Id | CNT_Email       | EMP_Id | Ranking |
+ ------ + ------------- + ----------- + ------ + --------------- + ------ + ------- +
| 1      | John Jacob    | 123 Ave.    | 1      | abc@email.com   | 1      | 1       |
| 1      | John Jacob    | 123 Ave.    | 2      | bcd@email.com   | 1      | 2       |
| 2      | Ermit Schmidt | 101 St.     | 3      | es@email.com    | 2      | 1       |
| 2      | Ermit Schmidt | 101 St.     | 4      | es12@email.com  | 2      | 2       |
| 2      | Ermit Schmidt | 101 St.     | 5      | es_01@email.com | 2      | 3       |
+ ------ + ------------- + ----------- + ------ + --------------- + ------ + ------- +
```

Now we can use the `Ranking` field to select emails, like so

```
select    emp.*
        , case cnt.Ranking when 1 then cnt.CNT_Email end as Email_1
        , case cnt.Ranking when 2 then cnt.CNT_Email end as Email_2
        , case cnt.Ranking when 3 then cnt.CNT_Email end as Email_3
    from #Employee emp
    left join (
        select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by emp_id order by cnt_id) as Ranking
            from #Contact
    ) cnt on cnt.EMP_Id = emp.EMP_Id
```

This produces the almost complete table:

```
+ ------ + ------------- + ----------- + ------------- + -------------- + --------------- +
| EMP_Id | EMP_Name      | EMP_Address | Email_1       | Email_2        | Email_3         |
+ ------ + ------------- + ----------- + ------------- + -------------- + --------------- +
| 1      | John Jacob    | 123 Ave.    | abc@email.com | NULL           | NULL            |
| 1      | John Jacob    | 123 Ave.    | NULL          | bcd@email.com  | NULL            |
| 2      | Ermit Schmidt | 101 St.     | es@email.com  | NULL           | NULL            |
| 2      | Ermit Schmidt | 101 St.     | NULL          | es12@email.com | NULL            |
| 2      | Ermit Schmidt | 101 St.     | NULL          | NULL           | es_01@email.com | 
+ ------ + ------------- + ----------- + ------------- + -------------- + --------------- +
```

Adding a simple group by gives us what we want

```
select    emp.*
        , max(case cnt.Ranking when 1 then cnt.CNT_Email end) as Email_1
        , max(case cnt.Ranking when 2 then cnt.CNT_Email end) as Email_2
        , max(case cnt.Ranking when 3 then cnt.CNT_Email end) as Email_3
    from #Employee emp
    left join (
        select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by emp_id order by cnt_id) as Ranking
            from #Contact
    ) cnt on cnt.EMP_Id = emp.EMP_Id
    group by  emp.EMP_Id
            , emp.EMP_Name
            , emp.EMP_Address


+ ------ + ------------- + ----------- + ------------- + -------------- + --------------- +
| EMP_Id | EMP_Name      | EMP_Address | Email_1       | Email_2        | Email_3         |
+ ------ + ------------- + ----------- + ------------- + -------------- + --------------- +
| 1      | John Jacob    | 123 Ave.    | abc@email.com | bcd@email.com  | NULL            |
| 2      | Ermit Schmidt | 101 St.     | es@email.com  | es12@email.com | es_01@email.com |
+ ------ + ------------- + ----------- + ------------- + -------------- + --------------- +
```

**2) Dynamic SQL**

Most of the above query remains unchanged regardless of how many email addresses an employee has. The only part that changes is found in the select portion; we must ask ourselves: "How do we know how many Emails to select"? In our example, we know that we need 3, but what if there is an employee with 4 or 8 or 100 email addresses? This is where Dynamic SQL comes in.

The idea is to build a string with a loop that constructs a SQL statement, which we will then execute. First, we need to know how many iterations we should loop, so we extract the maximum rank in the `#Contact` table, like so

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#max_rank') is not null drop table #max_rank
select top 1 COUNT(*) as Max_Rank
    into #max_rank
    from #Contact
    group by EMP_Id
    order by count(*) desc

declare @max_rank int
select @max_rank = Max_Rank from #max_rank

print @max_rank
```

Next, we write a loop that builds the `max(case ...)` portion of the query

```
declare @sql varchar(max) = ''

declare @iter int = 1
while @iter <= @max_rank
begin
    set @sql = @sql + '
        , max(case cnt.Ranking when ' + cast(@iter as varchar(max)) + ' then cnt.CNT_Email end) as Email_' + cast(@iter as varchar(max))
    set @iter = @iter+1
end

print @sql
```

Then we append the rest of the query that doesn't change

```
set @sql = 
'select    emp.*'
    + @sql
    + '
    from #Employee emp
    left join (
        select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by emp_id order by cnt_id) as Ranking
            from #Contact
    ) cnt on cnt.EMP_Id = emp.EMP_Id
    group by  emp.EMP_Id
            , emp.EMP_Name
            , emp.EMP_Address'

print @sql
```

**Putting this all together**, we get the complete code

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#max_rank') is not null drop table #max_rank
select top 1 COUNT(*) as Max_Rank
    into #max_rank
    from #Contact
    group by EMP_Id
    order by count(*) desc

declare @max_rank int
select @max_rank = Max_Rank from #max_rank

declare @sql varchar(max) = ''

declare @iter int = 1
while @iter <= @max_rank
begin
    set @sql = @sql + '
        , max(case cnt.Ranking when ' + cast(@iter as varchar(max)) + ' then cnt.CNT_Email end) as Email_' + cast(@iter as varchar(max))
    set @iter = @iter+1
end

set @sql = 
'select    emp.*'
    + @sql
    + '
    from #Employee emp
    left join (
        select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by emp_id order by cnt_id) as Ranking
        from #Contact
    ) cnt on cnt.EMP_Id = emp.EMP_Id
    group by  emp.EMP_Id
            , emp.EMP_Name
            , emp.EMP_Address'

print @sql
exec(@sql)
```

Hope this helps! And I also hope you're using SQL Server, haha.

Comment: Well, it is a oracle database used with a connection through visual studio.

Comment: I'd probably use ROW_NUMBER() here instead of RANK() even though it's probably fine since cnt_id should be unique. If however the Order by field was changed you could potentially get more than one record per employee with the same RANK. There's also no good reason to use RANK here

Comment: @MonkeyWithMachine Oracle also supports Dynamic SQL. I've never used Oracle before, so I don't know how much of the above query needs to change, but hopefully the modification will be easy enough.

Comment: AWESOME. Thank you @kindaTechy.